# Wikimedia : Hyperlink Criteria

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to analyze wiktionary using google page rank algorithm

But before dive into practical analysis want to check the concrete criteria set inside the community of wiktionary how the insiders add the hyperlink with whcih criteria.

How could I get to this information?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, please rephrase.

Comment: If you look into the Wiktionary there's a definition and a few selected words in that definition given the hyperlink.

Comment: Are you asking how you could obtain a list of definitions from a wiktionary page? (English  Wiktionary? Or any?)